# Lotus Notes Traveler server did not respond within the allotted time frame

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, connection-timeout

I have Lotus Notes Traveler 8.5.3.200 Build 201411031333 running on Lotus Domino server Release 8.5.3FP6 November 21, 2013 on a Windows/64 (2 Processors) platform  This server is dedicated for Traveler only, no other addons like Sametime or other is installed on this pc.

Problem is When I access Traveler via mobile or browser, it usually gives me following error (sometimes after succesfull login and sometimes always)

```
Lotus Notes Traveler server did not respond within the allotted time frame.
```

and on Server I can see errors like following

```
JVM: Traveler: Lotus Traveler task did not respond within the allotted time frame (55,000 milliseconds) for action GET and operation key
```

It happens very frequently, So far I have tried various suggestions available on the different forums example:

Started Traveler with Defrag ...

Added the following lines to the Notes.ini to bind the ip (as suggested at some blog)

NTS_IPC_TCP_Port=50125,192.168.1.1
NTS_IPC_TCP_Port2=50126,192.168.1.1

Added the following line to the servlet.properties file (in Server Data folder). (as suggested at some blog)
Text

ntstimeoutsyncas=230000

But no use still getting errors and timeout frequently.The server is for Local LAN connected users which are directly connected on same subnet without any firewall, also it is serving external internet base mobile users as well. Sometimes the page opens perfectly without delay, but most of time it gives timeout error. when there is timeout error, all mobile devices are unable to synch. After few retries they somehow manage to sync sometime.

I have disabled the Symantec Antivirus and backup exec agent as well but no use.

The real problem comes when I have to register new device by visiting traveler portal like http://traveler_server/traveler and it gives time out several times :(
When i restart the traveler server, it works fine for few minutes, then it starts making problem.
this is traveler status command output
[0230:07A9-0C3C]  There have been 9 device sync failures for reasons other than the server is too busy.
[0230:07A9-0C3C] The overall status of Lotus Notes Traveler is Yellow.

its green when i restart the server, but then goes to yellow after few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command's from the Domino console:

```
Tell HTTP Quit
Tell Traveler Quit
Load Traveler -defrag
```